# Class Design and Separation Of Concerns

Tags: c#, design, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC application and am wondering about the best way to design one of my models.

I have a class called RightLeftPersonToggle which represents two select list boxes on the page. The user is able to move "persons" between the left and right box using buttons between them.

This class can represent both a vehicle driver or manager so the load and save code is different for each type. The class is below.

```
public class RightLeftPersonToggle
{
    public RightLeftPersonToggle()
    {
        LeftList = new List<Person>();
        RightList = new List<Person>();
    }

    public List<Person> LeftList { get; set; }
    public List<Person> RightList { get; set; }
    public string LeftListTitle { get; set; }
    public string RightListTitle { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering what the best way to handle the loading and saving of the lists is. I've come up with two solutions but I'm not sure on which one is best.

1) The controller (or parent model) is responsible for loading and saving both LeftList and RightList. The RightLeftPersonToggle class has no knowledge of that code and remains exactly like the code above.

2) RightLeftPersonToggle gets two methods (one for save and one for load) which take functions as parameters to tell it how to do its job.

```
public void LoadAndFilterLists(Func<List<Person>> leftListFilter, Func<List<Person>> rightListFilter)

public void LoadSaveLists(Func<List<Person>> leftListSave, Func<List<Person>> rightListSave)
```

Solution number one keeps the code more simple in my opinion while solution number two seems to provide better sepration of concerns since RightLeftPersonToggle should know how to load and save itself.

Keeping in mind the fact that RightLeftPersonToggle doesn't always load and save data the same way, which of my proposed solutions would be considered best practice? Do you have any other recommendations for improvement?

Comment: IMHO there's no "a manager is a person relation" in the OOP sense. Rather, a person has a manager position. If you could refactor your domain model in that way, it'd be the best solution for this use case.

Comment: @Falcon Try not to let the business domain cloud the question. I only used the type of person as illustration that we will have different save and load functions. 

These left and right toggle boxes are tied very loosely to the business domain and are just controls to white list a person to a feature. If they are in the left box they get it, if they are in the right box they don't.

Comment: Why should "RightLeftPersonToggle" know how to load and save itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the logic needed to save the data differs depending on what's being shown in the lists, you should have the controller handle saving the lists. The code you've shown seems to be for your view, so all it should worry about is displaying the lists and shouldn't need to know what's actually in them. Let the controller figure out what type of data is in the 2 lists and what the appropriate save logic would be.

Comment: I have to agree. If this class is only used for displaying data then it shouldn't be in charge of Saving/Loading data. That is the Controller's job.

Answer (score 2):

In a more general sense, I would have my business classes represent the real-world relationships.  When a non-technical person is speaking about a Person, are they really talking about a Person's LeftList and RightList?  Or is this more of a hierarchical relationship?

The use of list boxes and such is a UI concern.  Your UI will be responsible for taking the set of list boxes and other input elements and mapping them over to objects that the domain model can work with.

Personally, I try to avoid exposing my domain model to my UI so I use a service layer that handles mapping between my entities and the DTOs that my UI works with.  The service layer also makes calls to the repository and I strive to keep all of my business logic in my entities.

The ASP.NET MVC UI takes the DTOs and maps them to view models and the views are strongly typed to view-specific view models.  The view models have awareness of UI components like SelectList but not the DTOs or entities.  The controllers are as thin as possible and coordinate service calls and returning views/redirects.

Comment: I see what your saying here. The list is really just a black or white thing. A person either has a feature (in the left side) or doesn't (in the right side). So my class as I've shown is fine for how the display but that is where it should stop and I should have the parent model worry about the loading and saving. Basically the hierarchy right now is that the controller creates a parent model and calls load on that. That load method is what sets up RightLeftPersonToggle. The controller has no knowledge of this class at all. Thin controllers and fat models is what I'm going for.

Comment: @Mike: "Thin controllers and fat models is what I'm going for." And a smart UI *g*

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas, one that I've struck off and the second which I favour.

1. My non-favoured idea: Why not create two sub classes of `RightLeftPersonToggle`, one for VehicleDriver and one for Manager, and implementing the Save/Load functionality in those subclasses? Your Parent class is responsible for creating the right type of class based on what kind of objects it is dealing with.
2. My second idea is to have your `RightLeftPersonToggle` class accept something like an `IPersonRepository` in the constructor, and call `_personRepository.Save` and `_personRepository.Load` from within the `RightLeftPersonToggle` class. It keeps the code separate, but still allows it to be called from the object repsonsible for it.

Comment: I think I like the 2nd idea better :)

Comment: I, too, like the second idea, +1 for it. I really dislike the first idea. That's like cloning an inheritance model for a problem that should already be solved by polymorphism.